# CKBuilder gives me too many plugins

Tags: ckeditor

In anticipation of making some modifications to ckeditor, I'm trying to build it from source, as described in the documentation [here](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_build). I want to build a version that is, as nearly as possible, identical to the version I already have installed on my production web server, so there won't be any surprises when I deploy my modified version later. Here are the steps I've followed:

1. Clone the git repository
2. `git checkout 4.3.3` (this is the version on the production server)
3. copy the build-config.js from the production server to ckeditor-dev/dev/builder/ (my production version came from the online builder; the config is at http://ckeditor.com/builder/059ce76c63ea2ff01636265c46f713c5)
4. `cd dev/builder ; ./build.sh`
5. there were complaints about missing plugins (scayt and wsc) so I downloaded them as zip files (scayt_4.3.3.zip and wsc_4.3.3.zip) and unzipped them in ckeditor-dev/plugins
6. tried `./build.sh` again

It apparently completed successfully, but the result in `release/ckeditor` is not a match for the production version as I had hoped. It contains a lot of plugins that I didn't ask for, and I know they're not dependencies of plugins I did ask for because the production version works fine without them. For example, I have `release/ckeditor/plugins/adobeair` which is not mentioned in my `build-config.js`.

The main `ckeditor.js` file is not a match for the production version either. i can see that part of the reason is that there is a different timestamp and version string ("4.3.3 DEV"), but there are lots of other changes too, which I can't easily examine because it's minified. And I can't really trust that this file was built correctly, since the plugin list wasn't built correctly. Also I can't break the build process down into smaller steps find out what it's doing because [there's no source](http://ckeditor.com/forums/Support/Where-are-the-sources-for-CKBuilder).

In a desperate move to try to understand what's going on, I reduced the plugin list in `build-config.js` to just the `about` plugin and ran `./build.sh` again. This caused `release/ckeditor/plugins` to get even bigger!

Can anyone explain why the `build.sh` can't give me anything close to the version I downloaded from the online builder?

(By the way, this question is here instead of on the CKEditor support forum because they wouldn't let me post it there. Called me a spammer!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CKBuilder which is used by the build script in https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev is exactly the one which is used by http://ckeditor.com/builder. The difference is caused by different arguments passed to it.

By default CKBuilder adds all plugins, even those omitted in `build-config.js`, to the package, although it doesn't merge them into the `ckeditor.js`. They are available to be enabled on demand. So `ckeditor.js` is not bigger than that downloaded from http://ckeditor.com/builder.

To build a package with only those plugins which you specified in `build-config.js` pass `-s` option to the build script:

```
> ./dev/builder/build.sh -s
```

You can also check other options:

```
> ./dev/builder/build.sh --help
```

As you'll find there it is possible to change the version, leave JS and CSS unminified etc.

PS. Sorry for the spam filter on forum.

Comment: That looks better. Thanks. I still wonder why removing plugins from the build-config caused more of them to appear... but it doesn't matter now.

Comment: Their directories appear, because plugins are removed from `ckeditor.js` back to those directories.

Comment: An update is needed to this answer: `build.sh --help` no longer works in recent versions. It ignores the `--help` and goes on building. If you want the help you have to find the jar and run it manually with `java ckbuilder.jar --help`

Comment: It might be a bug in the build script. I'll discuss this with the team first.

Comment: It appears to work in the ckeditor-dev.git repo in ./dev/builder/build.sh. Worth noting though that if you are using the ckeditor-preset.git repo, ./build.sh --help doesn't give you the same output, it just says `Usage: ./build.sh basic|standard|full [all]`.