# Incorrect build output when using ckbuilder

Tags: ckeditor4.x

I had downloaded CKEDITOR version 4.5.5 and used the online CKBUILDER tool to remove the plugins not required. Now I need to add one more plugin - 'clipboard', to do so I am following the steps mentioned below:

1. git clone https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev.git branch 4.5.x
2. copy pasted the build-config.js file from my downloaded version and added one plugin to the plugin list
3. edited build.sh from VERSION="4.5.11 dev" to VERSION="4.5.5"
4. ran build.sh

I still see all the plugins getting generated in release/ckeditor folder. But the excluded plugins are not built with ckeditor.js file. Thus I have only copied 'clipboard' plugin folder, ckeditor.js file and the lang folder. Does this seem correct or shall I copy all the previous plugins too?

Is my approach correct to get the correct version build by changing the VERSION variable to 4.5.5?

Comment: Answered by: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22354231/ckbuilder-gives-me-too-many-plugins

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CKBuilder gives me too many plugins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22354231/ckbuilder-gives-me-too-many-plugins)